# 19.10 Lubuntu: can't detect Intel 9462 WiFi adapter after dist-upgrade

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, lubuntu, iwlwifi

I co-installed Lubuntu Eoan Ermine on a new (previously Windows-only) laptop. On Windows, the WiFI works well. When I installed Lubuntu (from bootable USB), I selected the WiFi network for the installation and everything was OK.  I then ran `apt update && apt dist-upgrade`, which also worked well in general.

But now I can't connect to my wifi network anymore. [Wicd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man8/wicd.8.html) does not show any WiFi networks, but Ethernet works. I also tried adding the WiFi manually.

I followed https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html.en  to find my Wireless adapter is not recognized now.

The adapter is an Intel Wireless-AC 9462, and I already tried downloading the drivers from the Intel homepage, which did not work either.

How may I troubleshoot this to get my WiFi back?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi chili555, it just says 
"modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Operation not permitted"

Comment: Did you include `sudo` in the command? It doesn't show too well on the preceding line in my comment.